# Solving Wave Pattern

Tags: linear-algebra

[Wave Pattern Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHOHN.png)

The wave in the image contains smaller waves in the large waves. I'm looking for a logical method or formula that I can use to find the highs and lows of the waves. At least highs and lows of the large wave. I'm completely lost on how to approach this. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to google "Fourier transform".

Comment: @YiFan Thank you, doing that now